# Easy/minimal way of doing I/O in a browser (Java)

Tags: java, http

For tests, I would like to have a mininmal way of showing information to a user and getting input from him/her in a browser, meaning that I run a Java program on some Tomcat, Wildfly, whatever and can do basic I/O in the spirit of `System.out` and `System.in`.

If this is too broad, please advice me how to make it more specific.

Comment: Not sure what to advise to make it more specific but definitely too broad IMO.

Comment: Set up a tiny [Spark-Framework](http://sparkjava.com/) server, create a single page with a `<div>` for output and a one-text-field-`<form>` for input, done. Tomcat seems a bit heavyweight for the case. Why not just use the console?

Comment: Consider asking it on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ with more specific decision criteria.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Thanks.